# Vue js - вставить компонент в компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Нужно сделать структуру как в Vuetify. То есть передавать в условную кнопку атрибуты.

```
<ifbutton google text="button text">
    <GoogleIcon class="google-btn__icon" />
</ifbutton>
```

То есть, когда я вызываю компонент, то я могу вставить внутрь него условную картинку или другой компонент

```
ifbutton.vue


<template>
  <button
    :class="[
      dark == true ? 'dark-btn' : '' || 
      green == true ? 'green-btn' : '' || 
      google == true ? 'google-btn' : ''
    ]"
  >
    {{ text }}
  </button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "IfButton",
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    options: {
        type: Object,
        required: false
    },
    green: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
    dark: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
    google: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Работаю на Vue и Nuxt, пока что новичок и слабо понимаю как нужно правильно это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vue реализует API распределения контента, вдохновлённое [текущим
> черновиком спецификации веб-компонентов](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/Slots-Proposal.md), используя элемент `<slot>` в
> качестве точек распространения контента.

Таким образом вам достаточно реализовать слот в компоненте `<ifbutton>`, чтобы он принимал вложенный контент(в том числе и компонент) и отображал его (Если компонент `<ifbutton>` не получит никакого контента или компонента, то по умолчанию будет вставлено содержимое `<slot>{{ text }}</slot>`). Например:

```
<button
 :class="[
 dark == true ? 'dark-btn' : '' || 
 green == true ? 'green-btn' : '' || 
 google == true ? 'google-btn' : ''
 ]"
>
 <slot>
   {{ text }}
 </slot>
</button>
```

И рабочий пример:

```js
Vue.component('google-icon', {
  template: `
  <div>
    Google кнопка(слот)
  </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('ifbutton', {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    },
    green: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
    dark: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
    google: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    },
  },
  template: `
      <button
        :class="[
          dark == true ? 'dark-btn' : '' || 
          green == true ? 'green-btn' : '' || 
          google == true ? 'google-btn' : ''
        ]"
      >
        <slot>
          {{ text }}
        </slot>
      </button>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ifbutton google text="button text">
    <google-icon class="google-btn__icon"></google-icon>
  </ifbutton>
  <ifbutton dark text="Другая кнопка(без слота)"></ifbutton>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло