# Как динамически передать компонент в другой компонент во Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть родительский компонент `<MainComponent />` и два дочерних `<ChildOneComponent />`, `<ChildTwoComponent />`

Вопрос: Как отобразить компонент `<ChildOneComponent />` или `<ChildTwoComponent />` в компоненте `<MainComponent />`?

Пример использования:

```
<MainComponent>
  {{ Сюда нужно динамически передавать компонент `<ChildOneComponent>` или `<ChildTwoComponent>` }}
</MainComponent>
```

Пытаюсь реализовать через слоты, но не выходит..

P.S. Весь лишний код импорта опущен для простоты примера.

Comment: Попробуй так `<component v-bind:is="ChildOneComponent"></component>`

Comment: Уже пробовал так, этот вариант мне не подходит. Иногда мне нужно передать несколько компонентов.

Comment: Попробуй тогда v-show или v-if (v-else | v-else-if), как вариант.

Comment: Что-то похожее здесь
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225454/vue-js-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82/1225501#1225501